# VB.NET passing function to Action parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to write something in VB.NET based on a C# solution that I have. In the C# solution I call the function with:

```
somefunction(s => Console.WriteLine(s)).Wait();
```

And the called method is:

```
public static Task somefuntion(Action<string> callback);
```

In VB.NET I have

```
somefunction(Function(s) Console.WriteLine(s)).Wait()

Public Shared somefunction(ByRef callback As Action(Of string)) As Task
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but vb.net lambda expressions sure are ugly... So glad I moved away from it to c#.

Comment: `ByRef` is probably not what you want unless `somefunction` might provide its own callback back to the caller (which doesn't appear to be happening here).  `ByVal` is probably what you want.  The `ByRef` / `ByVal` distinction is somewhat confusing with reference types, where it refers to whether the host variable passed as an argument might be re-pointed to a different object, rather than whether a copy of the object is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. in lambda change `Function(s)` to `Sub(s)`:

```
somefunction(Sub(s) Console.WriteLine(s)).Wait()
```

b. add the `Function` keyword to the `somefunction` method-signature:

```
Public Shared Function somefunction(ByRef callback As Action(Of String)) As Task
```

Comment: passing Sub() myRoutine as a paramter for Action saved my day. Thank you very much

Comment: And for several lines?

Sub(s) Console.WriteLine(s) Console.WriteLine("") ??

Comment: @Kiquenet you can write multi line, but in this case you need add `End Sub`. see here: [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Check the offical doc

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

```
Module TestAction1
   Public Sub Main
      Dim messageTarget As Action(Of String) 

      If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1 Then
         messageTarget = AddressOf ShowWindowsMessage
      Else
         messageTarget = AddressOf Console.WriteLine
      End If
      messageTarget("Hello, World!")
   End Sub

   Private Sub ShowWindowsMessage(message As String)
      MsgBox(message)
   End Sub   
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Sub instead of Function:
`somefunction(Sub(s) Console.WriteLine(s)).Wait()`